# IOS UISegmentedController selecting Keyboard

Tags: ios

is it possible to use a UISegmentedController to determine the key board type is available to the user? For example I want the user to have a numeric keyboard if one segment is activated and the default keyboard when the other segment is activated:

```
if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Seg1");
    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad];
    //enter numbers

    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [self.myTextField reloadInputViews];
}
else if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"seg0");
    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    // enter words

    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [self.myTextField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Im sure Im missing something. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the type before you display the keyboard.

Change:

```
[self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[self.myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad];
```

To:

```
[self.myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad];
[self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Hi Ray thanks for your help on this. Its helped me fix it. Thanks